# output data based on two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need to output a table based on two other tables as shown below:

[image: table and output]

case: there are two table "tbl_schedule" and "tbl_report"

this is my script:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT*, count(*) as schedule_date FROM mst_schedule WHERE schedule_date LIKE '%$date' GROUP BY schedule_account") or die (mysql_error());
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$account = schAccount($data['schedule_account']);
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trn_reportsch WHERE schedule_id='$data[schedule_id]' GROUP BY schedule_id");
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".ucfirst($account['admin_fullname'])."</td>";
while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
echo "<td>".$data2['rating']."</td>";
}
echo "<td>".$data['schedule_date']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

So far I don't get the desired output. How should I change the script?

Comment: What you mean by bad, good and all?

Comment: regarding to question: it's a mess. you better need put data to the arrays and then just output as you wish. besides sql queries in `while` is just terrible for productivity

Comment: hi @SanjayKumarNS bad, good and very good. The value is taken from the record of the ratings given to user admin.

Comment: dear @MarkZucchini can you give me example script?

Comment: I understood your question. You want output to be like last table in PHP code. right?

Comment: I understands. But can you be more descriptive to indicate what flag for bad, good and very good.

Comment: hy @AshishChoudhary yes,, your right can you help please

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS , this flag bad is numeric 0 until 2
flag good is numeric 2 until 3
flag very good is numeric 4 until 5

Comment: @akashi I can check with your profile that you have not selected any answer in any of the questions you asked. Please accept the answers and upvote if you think it helped you in finding the solution you were looking for.

Comment: @akashi I wish I could, but my mariadb server doesn't work right now. so, i can't help you. but all you need is properly sql query, which will create temporary sql table with results same in the picture.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary , thx for your reminder. i'm already accept the answer and upvote :D and thx for your help

Comment: @MarkZucchini no problem mark, thx for your advice :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct.

Add following lines:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT*, count(*) as schedule_date FROM mst_schedule WHERE schedule_date LIKE '%$date' GROUP BY schedule_account") or die(mysql_error());
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $account = schAccount($data['schedule_account']);
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trn_reportsch WHERE schedule_id='$data[schedule_id]' GROUP BY schedule_id");
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . ucfirst($account['admin_fullname']) . "</td>";

    $bad = $good = $vGood = 0; // <-- ADD THIS LINE

    while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        if($data2['rating'] <=2){ // BAD
            $bad++;
        } else if($data2['rating'] <= 3){ // GOOD
            $good++;
        } else if($data2['rating'] > 3){ // VERY GOOD
            $vGood++;
        }
    }
    echo "<td>" . $bad . "</td>"; // Display the final value for bad
    echo "<td>" . $good . "</td>"; // Display the final value for good
    echo "<td>" . $vGood . "</td>"; // Display the final value for very good
    echo "<td>" . $data['schedule_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```